# Wordpress Custom Field Template plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i wanted to use custom field below wordpress post. i followed this tutorials 
http://idratherbewriting.com/2010/09/11/wordpress-tip-adding-custom-fields-in-posts/
but i am facing some problem to doing this. when i put the code on function.php file it show error. have a look please
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55782889/wordpress.PNG

Thanks
Rasel

Comment: Please, don't post a snapshot of your code, paste it in the Question. Just [edit] it. And check this little guides: [About] and [ask].

Comment: The first thing you'll need to do is replace &gt; with >